# Почему <map> содержит std::data()?

Tags: c++, map

Хедер `<map>` [содержит](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/map) функцию `std::data()`. Однако следующий код не компилируется:

```
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::data(std::map<int,int>{});
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'data(std::map<int, int>)'

Зачем тогда она в нём, если для этого класса неприменима?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data

Comment: @EugeneX что на этой странице отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: а разве нет? Или просто, лень прочитать?

Comment: @EugeneX я прочитал, но не нашёл там ответа на вопрос

Comment: Поясняю, std::data даёт прямой доступ к итератору обьекта,  для чего это нужно. Например для строки, что-бы получит указатель первого символа+n, для std::map это нужно для работы например for each `for (auto pair: myMap)`

Comment: @EugeneX может быть `std::data()` где-то и используется в реализации `std::map`, но эта функция не является частью публичного API этого класса, а значит в стандартном хедере не должна присутствовать (но может присутствовать в файлах реализации, скрытых от пользователя); для работы range-for для C-массива мы же не должны включать `<iterator>`; для работы вашего примера мы же не обязаны включать `<utility>` (для `std::pair`)

Comment: ну приехали, ты начал перемешивать примитивы с ооп.

Comment: @EugeneX понятие публичного API относится не только к ООП (функциям-членам), но и к свободным функциям. Если функция есть в хедере, то она является частью API, если же только в .cpp файле, то не является

Comment: А как быть в случае если функция есть в хедере, но без реализации в C++, например это часть компилятора самого С++, или внешне скомпилированый байткод. Не факт что она вообще существует. Но описана она должна быть в любом случае.

Answer (score 3):

Корректный, но бесполезный ответ: потому что так в стандарте сказано.

Конкретно, [iterator.range#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range#1.sentence-1) говорит что `std::data` (и другие схожие шаблоны) должно быть видно в `<map>` (и других хедерах):

> In addition to being available via inclusion of the `<iterator>` header, the function templates in `[iterator.range]` are available when any of the following headers are included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_­list>`, `<list>`, `<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<span>`, `<string>`, `<string_­view>`, `<unordered_­map>`, `<unordered_­set>`, and `<vector>`

где "in [iterator.range]" мы находим `begin`, `end`, `cbegin`, `cend`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `crbegin`, `crend`, `size`, `ssize`, `empty`, и `data`

Добавил `std::data` в стандарт документ [n4280](https://wg21.link/n4280) [PDF] (первая версия - [n4017](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm)) - похоже автор решил не затруднять всем жизнь и добавил новые близкородственные шаблоны одной пачкой. Несмотря на то, что `std::data` действительно не работает с `std::map`.